# Find and eliminate contours opencv

Tags: java, image, opencv, contour

I am working on a program that extracts the stickers on the puzzle and then later on finds the RGB of them. Currently, I am at the point where I want to remove any contours that aren't "square" like. I was wondering how I could do this.

What I do is I load the image, gray it, blur it, canny edge detection, dilate it find contours and draw them.

Is there a way I can draw around the contours instead of filling them in? And remove contours that aren't roughly the same size around or have almost 90 degree angles?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    Mat capturedFrame = Imgcodecs.imread("first.png");

    //Gray
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(capturedFrame, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    //Blur
    Mat blur = new Mat();
    Imgproc.blur(gray, blur, new Size(3,3));
    //Canny image
    Mat canny = new Mat();
    Imgproc.Canny(blur, canny, 20, 40, 3, true);

    Imgcodecs.imwrite("test.png", canny);

    //System.exit(0);
    Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(1, new Size(3,3));
    Mat dilated = new Mat();
    Imgproc.dilate(canny,dilated, kernel);

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    //find contours
    Imgproc.findContours(dilated, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    //draw contours

    Imgproc.cvtColor(capturedFrame, capturedFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        Imgproc.drawContours(capturedFrame, contours, i, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
    }

    Imgcodecs.imwrite("after.png", capturedFrame);

    Imshow img = new Imshow("firstImg");    
    img.show(capturedFrame);
}
```

Here is the initial image:

[image]

Here is the image with the contours drawn:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw non filled contours use non negative thickness: Imgproc.drawContours(capturedFrame, contours, i, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1); for instance.

To remove unnecessary find contour area, and just skip too large or too small of them when drawing.

Comment: Thanks I now am drawing around the contour :). Is there a way I could make it more "flexible" like looking if it has some sort of square shape, like the lengths of the sides are the same and or has almost 90 degrees in the contour? The reason I ask is because the image won't always be this one because it is a captured frame the cube could be captured closer or further away.

Comment: Sure you can find minAreaRect if your contour area will be near minAreaRect area, this will mean that your contour is near rectangular shape. You can control if it square, by finding ratio of minRect sides.